# Facebook API - get public images

Tags: facebook, api

I am new to use Facebook API in an android app. I m trying to access all public images from facebook using facebook API where user can get all pictures with given location from facebook.

How is it possible?

Comment: that is not possible at all. learn about facebook login, authorize the user with user_photos and get his photos with the /me/photos endpoint. and please read the docs and do some programming/testing before asking.

Comment: @luschn i am interested in  public images with specific location from different pages or any user.
plz help me its my final year project if thats not possible then i will fail my fyp

Comment: as i said, that´s not possible at all. you can´t get public images, and you certainly can´t get them by location either. you can only get pictures from a specific page or a specific user - if that user authorized your app, and only then.

Comment: i did some testing, there is a workaround. it only works for pages though.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible, there is only another possibility, a workaround:

- Get Facebook Places by location - it seems to work even without specifying the "q" parameter for a name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search
- Get photos for those Facebook Places: `/place-id/photos`

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/